# I'm having trouble running my Rails web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, webserver

I have installed ruby193 and I've installed rails via the command prompt (I also installed a DevKit). However, whenever I try the command:

```
rails server
```

I get this error:

```
←[31mCould not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available
on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

I've tried a bundle install and it gives me an error with when trying to install the json gem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

make sure in your Gemfile you are including the right gem (no misspellings, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on Windows.

I defeated the very same problem on Windows by manually installing my gems from `Gemfile` (`gem install gem_to_install`). After successfully installing a particular gem I ran `bundle check` to see what else I need to install. And this way after few installed gems I ran `bundle check` again and saw the output `The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied`.

And then server started. I wish you the same!

P.S. You can install few gems at once: `gem install gem1 gem2`.